# string not modifying python

Tags: python, chat

I'm working on someone else's code and I can't understand it. I must mess with the message string before sending it so as a test I decided to try and add a dot at the end of it but it doesn't add it when I send the message.

```py
case _:
  if self.whisper_lock:
    if not message.split(" ")[0] in ("/whisper", "/w", "/reply", "/r") or message.startswith(" "):
      self.print_msg("{}|{}| {}".format(termcolor.colored("-NIL-", self.args["timestamp_color"]),
                     termcolor.colored("CLIENT", self.args["client_color"]),
                     termcolor.colored("Whisper lock active, toggle it off to send messages", self.args["client_color"])))
      return

  # Add a dot at the end of the message
  message += "."
  self.send(json.dumps({"cmd": "chat", "text": message}))
```

can someone help?

Comment: Maybe the `if` conditions are true, so it's returning before that.

Comment: Can you add a sample of the `json` string that you see from the `self.send()` call?

Comment: If that code makes it to `message += "."`, you'd get a period on the end, guaranteed. So, something else is happening. You could `print(message)` just before the send to verify (or perhaps that self.print_msg is a simple print doesn't work here).

Comment: Perhaps `self.send()` is being called somewhere else, and **that** is the message you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the method doesn't return a message for you to append a dot.

Can you try adding a dot to the template passed to self.print_msg like this:

```
case _:
  if self.whisper_lock:
    if not message.split(" ")[0] in ("/whisper", "/w", "/reply", "/r") or message.startswith(" "):
      self.print_msg("{}|{}| {}.".format(termcolor.colored("-NIL-", self.args["timestamp_color"]),
                     termcolor.colored("CLIENT", self.args["client_color"]),
                     termcolor.colored("Whisper lock active, toggle it off to send messages", self.args["client_color"])))
      return

  self.send(json.dumps({"cmd": "chat", "text": message}))
```